# Using scrape() with CompositeMetricsRegistry

Tags: micrometer

I am currently using PrometheusMeterRegistry class, but would prefer to use CompositeMeterRegistry with the prometheus registry as part of that. However, there is no elegant way to access the scrape() method needed for the prometheus /metrics endpoint. Is there some way around this, or is it not recommended to combine the two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since only the `PrometheusMeterRegistry` has the `scrape` method, adding one to the `CompositeMeterRegistry` would not make too much sense.

Prometheus is pull based and most of the backends are push based. Having a scrape method makes sense for pull based registries but for push based ones you don't need it and `CompositeMeterRegistry` supports all type of registries.

When you setup your `CompositeMeterRegistry`, you can keep a reference to the `PrometheusMeterRegistry` and inject it where you create your `/metrics` endpoint. Everywhere else, you can use the composite.

Comment: Thanks for your response, what do you suggest is the best way to do this?

Comment: The final paragraph on Jonatan's answer is the best way forward: add the PrometheusMeterRegistry to the Composite, and use that Prometheus registry for the scrape endpoint.